# Study Room Reservation Program

Tags: c

I'm having trouble figuring out how to go about making a program for reserving study rooms.
1. Am I going in the right direction as far as getting the user input for the menu?
2. Once the user selects an option, how can i assign their room selection a new value to appear as open or unavailable? (Pointers?)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
int rm1 = 0;
int rm2 = 0;
int rm3 = 0;
int rm4 = 0;
int rm5 = 0;
int rm6 = 0;
int rm7 = 0;
int rm8 = 0;
int rm9 = 0;
int rm10 = 0;
int input;

while (input != 4)
{

    printf("Welcome to the Study-Room-Reservation System.\n"); /* Asks for user entry */
    printf("Please Select an Option.\n------------------------------------\n");
    printf("1. Reserve study room.\n");
    printf("2. Leave study room.\n");
    printf("3. Check Availability.\n");
    printf("4. Exit.\n");

    scanf("%d", &input);

    if (input == 1)
    {
        printf("Please enter room number you would like to reserve. \n");/* 1. Reserve a room */
        scanf("%d" , &)
    }

    else if (input == 2)
    {
        printf("Please enter room number you would like to exit. \n"); /* 2. Exit a room */
    }

    else if (input == 3)
    {
        printf("The following rooms are available. \n"); /* 3. Show available rooms */
    }

    else
    {
        printf("Invalid Command.\n"); /* Invalid Command */
    }
}



return 0;
}
```

Comment: `input` is not initialized.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
int rm1 = 0;
int rm2 = 0;
int rm3 = 0;
.
.
```

use an array

```
int room[10]; //for 10 rooms
```

then use it in a way like,

```
if( room[i] == 0 )
    //room vacant
else if( room[i] == 1 )
    //room occupied
```